# UWP c# - Can't use file after being filepicked

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to upload a file on amazon s3, after filepicked it.

To start, I do this :

```
       var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
       picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
       picker.SuggestedStartLocation =
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
       picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

       Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

so here, `file` is picked and ready to be use.

After that, I try to upload it, like that :

```
        if (file != null)
        {
            upload(file.Path);
        }
       ...

      public async Task<string> upload(string path)
        {
           TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(...);
           await utility.UploadAsync(path,key, bucket); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM

        }
```

and so , this is the error I catched :

> Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Acces denied.
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   PCLStorage.WinRTFileSystem.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()    at
>   Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.validate(TransferUtilityUploadRequest
>   request)    at
>   Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.GetUploadCommand(TransferUtilityUploadRequest
>   request, SemaphoreSlim asyncThrottler)    at
>   Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.UploadAsync(String filePath, String
>   bucketName, String key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Tilkee.Upload.d__0.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Acces denied.

I tried to put it in another Task async, but same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: The filepicker should just get the name of the file and not open the file.  There are different versions of file picker and you should use one that doesn't open file, just get name of file.

Comment: How can I just get the path of the file instead of open it ?

Comment: In a form application it is : OpenFileDialog (not FileOpen).

Comment: this doesn't exist in UWP (universal application)

Comment: I'd check the `Access Denied` part of the stacktrace. Did you make sure to specify all of the needed access rights in the application manifest ?

Comment: I'm kinda new to this UWP development, I had the file open rights in the package manifest, but the error persist

Comment: The path of the file isn't something you can always access in UWP, when you open a file the file picker returns a StorageFile object which contains the data for the file, if you can use UploadAsync with an IO.Stream it's possible to get that from the storage file, think of the picker as getting the file, the path is a property you don't have permission to access that unless you use FutureAccessList - not used this myself but might help if can only use Path

Answer (score 2):

We cannot access files using its path unless the file is in the accessible location like app installation folder, known folders like music lib since UWP apps are isolated and run in sandbox. `FileOpenPicker` helps in the app to let user choose to broke the app container and access to the files, yes, we can then access this file for example using stream, we can also get the path of this file, but the path here cannot be used to access this file again when you want to upload this file. For more information, you can refer to [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/).

My suggestion is that after the file is picked, access the file stream and try to upload this file stream.